Is there a way to make the compiler raise an error instead of allowing unsigned int wrapping?
Disclaimer: I am a C++ and programming noob
I was making a Profile class as an exercise (from the book I am reading) which would hold the names and ages of profiles/people. The invariant I defined for the class state was: no duplicate usernames, no empty names (empty string) and no negative ages.
I thought preventing callers from adding negative ages to profiles could be done by representing the age as a unsigned int like this:
typedef std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> name_age_pair;

void Profiles::add_profile(const std::string& username, const unsigned int age)
{
    if (is_name_dup(username)) throw std::invalid_argument("Name is duplicate");
    if (usernamename.empty()) throw std::invalid_argument("Name cannot be empty string");
    all_profiles.push_back(name_age_pair(username, age));
}

I expected that the compiler would stop callers from passing negative integers as ages, but I was wrong. The integers just wraps around instead:
int main()
{
    Profiles school_profiles{};
    school_profiles.add_profile("Gunter", -1);
    school_profiles.print_profiles(); // Gunter - 4294967295 
}

Sure I could just change the type of age to a normal int and check if the age arguments is negative with a if-statement. But out of curiosity is there a way to make the compiler raise a error instead of allowing the wrapping when a negative argument is given.

Unsigned's modulo arithmetic ("wrapping") is an intended feature of unsigned integers and one of the few reasons to actually use them. I wouldn't expect any compiler to provide warnings about it. Using a signed integer is better when you don't want negative values, because you can inspect the value and throw if it is negative.

C++ has implicit conversions and promotions, which is a behavior it inherited from C.  Efforts to change that behavior have not gained any traction with the WG21 standards committee (e.g., Sutter's C++ syntax 2 experiment, or Baxter's Circle experiment and New Circle experiment).

@Clifford This is not fully correct. -1 is a literal, so a compiler could catch such an input, like it already forbids doing unsigned int ui{-1};.

@Evg not sure how that comment got posted.  I  thought I'd abandoned it.  Deleted now.  That said a hard coded age value seems somewhat unlikely, or at least not particularly useful.

@Evg -- the difference is that unsigned int ui = -1; has been valid and has a well defined meaning since forever; disallowing it would break existing code. unsigned int ui{-1}; uses the (relatively) new initialization syntax, and when that syntax was added narrowing conversions were intentionally not allowed.

You can turn on warnings on your compiler. If you're using gcc, add the flag -Wsign-conversion to make the compiler warn you about integer sign conversions. You can also add the flag -Werr to make gcc treat warnings as errors and fail to compile when there is an implicit conversion. This would only work when you write literal values as you do in the example with "Gunter".

You've run into the quintessential example of a precondition/contract: rejecting negative integers.
Using unsigned integers is generally the wrong approach to deal with this problem, for multiple reasons:

Implicit conversion like in your case will make the function callable with -1.
You now work with unsigned (modular) arithmetic within the function, and this is nonsensical because an age is not modular.

Don't confuse unsigned for a type that's just there to prevent negative values.
Similarly, std::sqrt takes a double, but this double is not allowed to be negative.
We don't need and want a hypothetical unsigned double to deal with this.
An age should not be unsigned
To illustrate the last point, consider what happens when you subtract two ages: you get a time difference. This difference can be negative depending on which age is lower.
A negative age is also meaningful because an age is simply the time difference from the point of birth; a negative age is the time until someone is born. You can easily run into such cases when doing math with ages, and it would be very tedious to convert between signed/unsigned constantly.
Possible alternatives
CppCoreGuidelines has a rule ES.106: Don’t try to avoid negative values by using unsigned, with the following sample solution:
struct Positive {
    int val;
    Positive(int x) :val{x} { Assert(0 < x); }
    operator int() { return val; }
};

int f(Positive arg) { return arg; }

int r1 = f(2);
int r2 = f(-2);  // throws

This is obviously over-simplified, but if you really wanted to, you could encapsulate non-negativity in some wrapper class.
In most cases, using an assert or an if statement that can throw to check if inputs are negative is totally fine, and any such wrapper is over-engineering.
If you're willing to wait a few years, there will also be C++26 contracts (presumably).
P2900R6 is one of many proposals working on this.
Among other features, this will allow you to specify pre-conditions and post-conditions for functions, such as:
void add_profile(const std::string& username, const int age) {
    pre (age >= 0);
    // ...
}

This is the ultimate solution to the problem, but it will take a few years until we can use it.
If you insist ...
If you really insisted on using unsigned integers despite everything said, the most simple C++20 solution would be:
void add_profile(const std::string& username, const std::unsigned_integral auto age)

This is an abbreviated function template where the age parameter is any type that satisfies the std::unsigned_integral concept.
If you provided say, int, there would be no implicit conversion; instead, the constraints of this function template wouldn't be satisfied, resulting in an error.

I feel like the two arguments against using unsigned is a problem of unsigned and not a problem of types vs preconditions. This reminds me of Herb Sutter's not_null<T> which is a pointer that shouldn't be null. That doesn't feel so wrong now does it? There's a few differences here: there's no implicit conversions from nullptr to not_null<T> and also non-null pointers are closed under (legal) pointer arithmetic. There's also no surprising behaviour differences between a regular pointer and not_null<T>.

@PasserBy I agree, and I've updated the question a bit to reflect that. There are decent ways of integrating these preconditions into the type system. One thing to consider though is that int* and not_null<int*> are distinct types, and this can be unergonomic at times, and result in extra template instantiations in generic code. Therefore, C++26 contracts are still an overall better solution.

You can do it with compile time checks to rule out implicit conversion, like this:
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

// Don't use pair make a struct
// using std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> name_age_pair;

struct name_age_t
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int age;
};

// your original signature allows for implicit conversions
void add_profile(const std::string& username, unsigned int age)
{
}

// pre C++20 use SFINAE (std::enable_if)
template<typename T>
auto add_profile_17(const std::string& username, T age) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<unsigned int,T>,void>
{
}

template<typename T>
concept UnsignedInt = std::is_same_v<unsigned int,T>;

// C++20 and later you can use `requires` (can be cleaned up with a con
void add_profile_20(const std::string& username, auto age ) requires UnsignedInt<decltype(age)>
{
}

int main()
{
    add_profile_17("Walter", 1u);
    add_profile_20("Walter", 1u);
        
    //add_profile_17("Walter", 1); // will not compile 1 is an int not an unsigned int
    //add_profile_17("Gunter", -1); // 

    // add_profile_20("Walter", 1); // again will not compile
    
}

